# Access array element by string in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

As we know its possible to access field by name using indexer.

```
var obj:* = {name:"Object 1"};
trace(obj["name"]); // "Object 1"
```

But how to access an array element by String?

```
var arr:Array = new Array();
var obj:* = {items:arr};
trace(obj["items[0]"]); // Undefined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, basically you want to be able to have a string be interpreted as actionscript. No elegant solution I'm afraid. You could write a parser that handles some simple syntax in a string and retrieves the value.

Here's a simple example:

```
var obj:Object = {
    items:[1, 2, 3], 
    subObj: {
        subitems: [4, 5, 6]
    }
};

trace(getValueInObject(obj, "items[0]")); // 1
trace(getValueInObject(obj, "subObj.subitems[2]")); // 6

// takes an object and a "path", and returns the value stored at the specified path.
// Handles dot syntax and []
function getValueInObject(obj : Object, pathToValue : String) : * {
    pathToValue = pathToValue.replace(/\[/g, ".").replace(/]/g, "");
    var pathFractions : Array = pathToValue.split(".");
    var currentObject : Object = obj;

    while (pathFractions.length > 0 && currentObject != null) {
        var fraction : String = pathFractions.shift();
        currentObject = currentObject[fraction];
    }

    if (currentObject != null) {
        return currentObject;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: I need something like this 'obj["items"][0]'. I know how to access array... -1

Comment: I have updated my original answer with a possible solution, I hope it's to some use.

Comment: That's what i though. Ty!